# Changing the start address of the IntelHex file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, hex, file-handling

I want to change the start address of the IntelHex file and also update the checksum. I am new to intelhex format and so I went through the documentation. I saw a attribute called `start_addr` and used it. But after that. it is not reflecting in the first line of the intelhex file.

PS: Pardon my writing style its my first time on stackoverflow.

My code -:

```
from intelhex import IntelHex
hx = IntelHex()
hx.fromfile('copy.hex', format='hex')2
hx.start_addr = {'EIP': 2149580800}
```

The first line of the intelhex file is -:

:0200000480007A

After running the code, the first line remains unchanged. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually [saving](https://python-intelhex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/part2-5.html) your changes to any file:

```py
hx.tofile('copy.hex', format='hex')
```